# Media query to detect a small (in inch) but high-width (in pixels) screen

Tags: css, media-queries

I've done a little work on my site to show smaller screens (in pixels) another navigation (bigger) than the larger screens.
Now this works on my desktop when resizing the browser window, but there are of course also mobile phones which have the same number of pixels as my desktop machine, but then in a very small screen (let's say 5 inches).

So what I want to do is: show the 'desktop' css not only when you have lots of pixels, but also when your screen is say 10 inch or larger.
Can I accomplish that with media queries?

This is what i have now:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style-mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 840px)" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style-desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 841px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style-desktop.css" media="print">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `resolution` in your media query to distinguish between devices of different pixel densities.

For instance to tend to a 288 dpi device where one logical pixel is three hardware pixels, use one of these

```
@media screen and (min-resolution: 3dppx) { ... }
@media screen and (min-resolution: 288dpi) { ... }
```

where dppx means dots per pixel, and dpi, of course, dots per inch.

See [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#resolution) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#resolution).

Comment: My desktop (21" monitor) is *"`288dpi`"* and *"`3dppx`"*. How do i use a media query to detect a small screen (whether that screen is 480px or 1440px wide)?

Comment: @IanBoyd To detect screen sizes, you use `device-width`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#device-width). So, `screen and (max-device-width: 480px)` for all screens 480px or less wide.

Comment: The problem is that i can have both a 3" wide screen, and 17" wide screen, both the same resolution (i.e. both `3dppx`, both `288dpi`, both `device-width: 1440`). I want to know when one user is handheld size.

Comment: I think you should ask a new question now, as this is off topic for this one. A 17" wide screen with 1440 pixels horizontally simply isn't 288 dpi. So something else is going on; what is it?

Comment: @IanBoyd could you give an example where dpi and device-width are the same but the (diagonal) screen size is different. In my view there aren't any.

Answer (score 1):

Add `device-pixel-ratio` and `resolution` to your media queries. To maximize cross-browser compatibility you should use something like this:

```
 @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),   /* Webkit-based browsers */
        (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),      /* Older Firefox browsers (prior to Firefox 16) */
        (min-resolution: 2dppx),               /* The standard way */
        (min-resolution: 192dpi) {             /* dppx fallback */  
         ...
      }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Pixel ratio values for different devices can be found here: http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/